# can php (wapache) run remote files?

Tags: php, desktop-application

i recently had a look at [Wapache](http://wapache.sourceforge.net/) and it sounds good for running our php applications as desktop apps. For one of our php projects, i need to deploy it as a desktop app in client's system, and wapache is my choice. For running the desktop app with wapache, i put all my project files in htdocs folder in wapache folder, which i can handle to the client.

But what i worry is that, with wapache, the source code is visible to other users, as the files are available in the htdocs folder of the wapache directory in client's machine, which i dont like.

So i have 2 options, one is to encrypt my source code, and other is to make the wapache run the remote files.

How can i achieve the second option, if at all, its possible?

Comment: I don't even know where to start...

Comment: If the code files are remote, what do you gain by installing anything on the client's machine?

Comment: I think you need to step back to reevaluate that "problem." Read @Jeffrey's comment a few more times until it sinks in. :o)

Comment: I just put the wapache folder in his system, which has Demo.exe file, that opens the inbuilt IE browser (without any toolbars or menus), with the files in the htdocs folder (index file). Now, instead of this default behaviour, can i make such that Demo.exe runs a remote file? Or can i run a remote file from that php index file, using frames?

Comment: Fine, i tried with an example of frames, and if i put the frame url to some external site, the site is opening in the external browser, rather than opening in the wapache browser. So currently it seems that encrypting my code would be the only option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wapache works well with ioncube encrypted files.

You can also separate the logic files from interface, then run logic files on server and get the data using curl, but this seems more complicated